# OpenLDAP ppolicy

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap

I'm looking into adding password expiry and forced change of password on first login, using OpenLDAP.
It seems to achieve this using the ppolicy overlay.

I started configuring OpenLDAP with ppolicy overlay, when I saw this in ppolicy.schema:

> Contents of this file are subject to change (including deletion)
>    without notice.
>
> Not recommended for production use!
>    Use with extreme caution!

How do everyone running OpenLDAP in production enforce password expiry, check password strength and such? Do everyone ignore this serious-looking warning?

Comment: Yes. The password policy is defined in a series of IETF draft RFCs, none of which has been become an RFC for some reason. However what is implemented in OpenLDAP has been stable for several years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are using it in production.
As the spec is not yet made final, we may have to deal with any changes that made later. (Hopefully not much changes to existing spec).

As the commenter said above, the implementation is stable and prod quality, its marked experimental because the spec has been made final yet. says [this](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/1204.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

In newer version of openldap we don't modify schema files or any other configuration files directly...If you wants to add/modify/delete some configuration we use ldapadd, ldapdelete and ldapmodify utilities.

Refer this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ldif-files-to-make-changes-to-an-openldap-system) from digitalocean.